# How to play selected combobox item in webbrowser component in c# windows forms?

Tags: c#

I have a few flash files listed in my combobox component of my WinForms application. Now if file is selected I want it to be played in webBrowser component, here is the code:

Adding files into combobox:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\folder\");

          foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        } 
    }
```

Playing flash file:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(comboBox1.SelectedText); //it doesnt work
    }
```

I can open flash files normally, it looks like I can't pass the selected value from combobox.

**UPDATE**

To make sure that this event is working, I changed it into:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.textBox1.Text = "adsfadsf";
        this.textBox2.Text = comboBox1.SelectedText;
}
```

When I change the selected item, string adsfadsf appears in textBox1, but textBox2 stays empty.

**UPDATE2**

**Here is the full code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\folder\");

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
        } 
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Text = "adsfadsf";
        this.textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedText;
       // this.webBrowser1.Navigate(comboBox1.SelectedText);
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What doesn't work? You get an 404 page? Or Exception or something? I can image you have to do something like this.webBrowser1.Navigate("file://" + comboBox1.SelectedText); to make clear it is a local path.

Comment: please can show us what will the filepath with name that must get played in the webBrowser

Comment: If i change `this.webBrowser1.Navigate(comboBox1.SelectedText);` into `textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedText;` it doesn't work too. It just doesn't pass argument into textBox1. I don't know why.

Comment: @pawel: did you debug and see whether the debugger goes in to the Select index change event?

Comment: please check update of my first post : )

Comment: I added the full code, It's short - maybe this will tell you something more : ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer to your question - use comboBox1.Text, not comboBox1.SelectedText.

The bigger issue here is that you could have quickly caught this if you had properly used the debugger.  In the event you don't know how to do this, a quick tutorial:

I'm using VS2008 for this, but it's pretty much the same in all versions.

First, set a breakpoint on your line of code that isn't working correctly.  Click in the left margin, and you'll get a red dot showing the breakpoint.

Next, run your code.  When you change the dropdown, the breakpoint will fire, and you'll go back to Visual Studio.  You can point the mouse over the "SelectedText" portion of "comboBox1.SelectedText", and see that it is showing any empty string, which is why your application isn't working as you intended.

Then hover over the "comboBox1" portion, and you'll see a small amount of info on the variable.  Click the "+" on the left, and it will expand.  You can scroll down through the properties and values, and see that the value you're looking for is in the "Text" property.